# Avoid hardcoded strings in UrlHelper.Action and ModelState.AddModelError

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, modelstate, urlhelper

I have the following code-lines:

```
return Json(new { redirectTo = UrlHelper.Action("Index", "Home") });
```

and

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Useraccount.Email", emailAlreadyExistsException.Message);
```

For both the UrlHelper.Action method and the ModelState.AddModelError Method I'd like to avoid the hardcoded strings. Is there a better possibility?

Comment: I hoped that I could use something like a RedirectToRouteResult for the UrlHelper.Action.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a constants file and use constants instead:

```
public static class Constants 
{
    public const string HomeController = "Home";
    public const string IndexAction = "Index";
    public const string UserAccountEmail = "Useraccount.Email";
}
```

Your code then becomes:

```
return Json(new { redirectTo = UrlHelper.Action(Constants.IndexAction, Constants.HomeController) });
```

and

```
ModelState.AddModelError(Constants.UserAccountEmail, emailAlreadyExistsException.Message);
```

As an alternative for validation, you could use a library like [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/)